# How is a user registered in hyperledger composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am trying to build a mobile application working against a blockchain network. The thing i am not understanding is how the user actually becomes a member( registered ) in the network. Suppose user open’s our applications than what credentials does he enter so that he becomes a participant in the network.

Answer (score 1):

In Composer the first thing to do is to create a `participant`, then using the Admin Card, `Issue an Identity` to the participant.  (Identity is a Hyperledger Fabric concept, and Composer is built on top of Fabric.)  Once the Identity has been Issued (and a card created) you can use that Identity.

I would suggest trying out Participant and Identities using the Composer Playground (either online, or installed locally).

If you haven't seen them, then the [Composer Tutorials](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/tutorials) are a good resource, then perhaps [look at this tutorial](https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc) that uses the Composer Rest Server in Multi-User mode.